# InlineCreateOperation with select 2 from ajax

Tags: select, inline

I'd like to combine a inlinecreate with a select2_from_ajax field, is it possible ?
Here is my issue :
When i select an application, i want to display the versions of the selected application
and i'd like add a version inline if the version not exists.
[Selected lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwvVq.jpg)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Could you answer to my issue please ?